# What is a reasonable percentage salary increase for tenure and promotion

Tags: united-states, tenure-track, salary

What is a reasonable percentage salary increase for tenure and promotion from assistant to associate professor in the US?

Comment: Are you really interested in what is reasonable based on changes in expectations and workload or what is common?

Comment: A lot of people could provide anecdotal data from their own institutions, but a better answer would provide some sort of aggregate statistics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data on faculty salaries is available from the AAUP survey:

http://chronicle.com/article/2013-14-AAUP-Faculty-Salary/145679/#id=table

Associate professors make, very roughly speaking, 10% more than assistant professors.  However, since professors get a few percent raise a year, you can estimate that the difference between the most experienced assistant professor and the least experienced associate professor is about the typical annual raise.  So, I think the answer is "not much."  However, it varies widely by institution, school, department, governance model, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure about your analysis.  At many universities, newly hired assistant professors make more than older ones because annual raises often don't match increases in the market rate for new hires.

Comment: @Kimball, I don't know of any longitudinal data.  That would be more suitable for answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

At my institution, for CS, I got 5% raise from promotion from assistant to associate prof (about $4500) and a 10% raise (about $10K) for associate to full prof. Not sure how it compares to other schools. I know this is a late answer, but hope it helps others.